# Can't see staring installation page of wordpress docker container based on alpine linux

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, docker, alpine-linux

Here is my configuration :

OS : Windows 10 Enterprise x64   [Version 10.0.14393]

Docker Toolbox: Docker version 1.12.5, build 7392c3b
                docker-compose version 1.9.0, build 2585387

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:4.7.0-php7.0-fpm-alpine
    links:
      - "mysql:mysql-database"
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 9000:9000
    expose:
      - "3306"
      - "8080"
      - "80"

    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example


  mysql:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    expose:
      - "3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

Starting up this with : `docker-compose up -d`

After this don't see wordpress installation page on http://192.168.99.100:8080/

If I change wordpress tag to 4.7.0-php7.0-apache then everything works fine .Is there bug in alpine wordpress image or I just need to open some ports?

Comment: With the `4.7.0-php7.0-fpm-alpine` tag it's not possible for your wordpress to connect to the mysqldb. the connection is refused. Check `docker logs`. I don't know why but if you check the difference in the dockerfiles of the tags you should probably find it.

Comment: Logs from alipne container :

Comment: 29-Dec-2016 12:30:36] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
[29-Dec-2016 12:30:36] NOTICE: ready to handle connections

Comment: Logs from mysql container: 2016-12-29T12:29:57.698912Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2016-12-29T12:29:57.708032Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2016-12-29T12:29:57.708189Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.17'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Answer (score 1):

this alpine image was made with just php-fpm and need to be used alongside with an webserver like nginx.

There is my approach:

In the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    volumes_from:
      - wordpress
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:4.7.0-php7.0-fpm-alpine
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
```

And the site.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name $hostname;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get error with this :ERROR: for web  Cannot create container for service web: Invalid bind mount spec "C:\\Users\\ExelleR\\Desktop\\Work\\wordpress\\site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro": Invalid volume specification: 'C:\Users\ExelleR\Desktop\Work\wordpress\site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: To prevent errors related to volume paths  in Windows using Docker Toolbox do : $env:COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1 in PowerShell . This happens because of docker-compose 1.9.0 .